# Android: Using Room and Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I wrote an app that saves and uses data in/from a Cloud Firestore database. I would want to organize more clearly than for the moment my files, for example by using DOs and DAOs.

I know the concept of "DAO" exists in Android Room.

However, [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) seems to define Android Room as a "local database". So if I understand it well, I shouldn't use it in addition to Firestore?

By the way, it would be the same with Firebase Cloud Realtime Database (a third database system).

## Edit :

I didn't understand the notion of "local" database (Room). Tamir, in his answer, corrected me. This question is off-topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So if I understand it well, I shouldn't use it in addition to Firestore?

No and this is beacause Cloud Firestore has [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) enabled by default:

> For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the PersistenceEnabled option to false.

This means that you'll have by default a local copy of your database. So there is no need to add another one.

Comment: Not quite agree. Most of is use Firebase free (spark) there are a imited number of calls. The idea having Room is to use the local database for all I/O and at the end of the day ahve a asynch job upload the data to Firestore. That way we keep it synch and we save lots of calls that could incurr in money spent.

Comment: @Javi The Spark (free) plan is for development and **not** for production. Doesn't matter if you make the changes one by one or all the changes at the end of the day, you'll always be built with the same number of write operations.

Comment: hi Alex, I want to know, if the user second time opens the app and there is no change to the data, will the app download the data again or will it use from local copy ?

Comment: @AlexMamo "It will get the data from the local cache" is this really true? Doug said ["If you have a listener that gets cut off because the app process was terminated by the OS, and later gets reattached when the app is launched again, you will be charged for another query."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63428651/12208004).

Comment: @user12208004 I think this **[article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)** will clear your doubts.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the article, but based on what Doug said above with my previous comment, "In the worst-case scenario, if the listener is disconnected every 31 minutes, we pay 50 reads each time. So this solution is feasible only when the listener is not often disconnected." this doesn't seem correct because if user terminate the app with closing it (detach listener) and open it (attach listener) again, the document read count is increased even within 30 min.

Comment: @user12208004 That's correct, "if" you detach the listener, meaning you implement that functionality but Doug's answer is very complete.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, when you are developing an app there would be some data that you will want to save into locally and other data that you will want to save on remote database, it's not a bad thing to have both remote and local database.
Some example that I can think of for saving your data remotely is to manage users - when a new user will be created you will want to check if the username is not taken, and you can't do it if this data is only stored locally.
And for using a local database - one of the major advantages in the local database vs remote database its the speed of writing and receiving data. 
[Here is a nice article on the subject.](https://www.contegix.com/cloud-storage-vs-local-storage-which-is-right-for-your-business/)

Comment: I didn't well undersand the concept of "locald atabase" (Room), thank you!